# SQL Rearange data from multiple cells into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a view that groups by a particular column (let's say BRAND) and all instances of a 2nd column (let's say COLOR) for each BRAND, grouped in a single cell and separated by semicolon. It's hard for me to put it in words but this is what I am looking for:

***FROM THIS TABLE***

```
|BRAND  |COLOR  |
|-------|-------|
|TOYOTA |BLUE   |
|NISSAN |BLUE   |
|FORD   |BLUE   |
|NISSAN |RED    |
|NISSAN |GREEN  |
|FORD   |RED    |
-----------------
```

***TO THIS VIEW***

```
|BRAND  |COLOR          |
|-------|---------------|
|TOYOTA |BLUE           |
|NISSAN |BLUE;RED;GREEN |
|FORD   |BLUE;RED       |
|-------|---------------|
```

I wish I could provide code but I have not come up with any ideas.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_concat`. here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hmRYcp7to6J4RF2BHwyjis/0).

```
select
  brand,
  group_concat(color order by color SEPARATOR ';' ) as color
from myTable
group by
  brand
```

output:

```
| brand  | color          |
| ------ | -------------- |
| FORD   | BLUE;RED       |
| NISSAN | BLUE;GREEN;RED |
| TOYOTA | BLUE           |
```

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the feedback, I have updated my answer.

Comment: If it matters, this returns colors in a different order from that implied by the desired result ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I am on SSMS and there is no group_concat function in it. Is there an analogous option?

Comment: @alexqr1 why did you tag `MySQL` then?

Comment: My mistake, I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: @alexqr1 are you using ms sql server?